# Wrong result on implementing a custom Method reference java

Tags: java

In the below code the first syso is printing 0 and second one is printing 20 why?

```
      collect2 =>  [2, 4, 6, 8]
          System.out.println(":1-> :"+collect2.stream().reduce(0,X::doSum));//0

        System.out.println(":2-> :"+collect2.stream().reduce(0,Integer::sum));//20
class X{

    public static Integer doSum(int val1,int val2){
        int sum = Integer.sum(val1, val1);
        return sum;

    }

}
```

Comment: What type is `collect2`? `ArrayList<Integer>`?

Comment: ArrayList<Integer>

Comment: Just spotted the typo. You wrote `Integer.sum(val1, val1);`. The second parameter should be `val2`, not `val1`.

Comment: You specified val1 twice in your static method.

Comment: Thank you, looking for only why it is not working instead of reviewing it

Comment: Reduce must be calling `doSum` with curent running total as `val1`, next number to add as `val2`; running total starts at zero, result (i.e., next running total) is `val1 + val1` which is always zero.